# How to know that user touches on which app icon?

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which I want to know that which application is opened by the user.
Like If the user opens play store, that I want to know that the play store is opened or user clicked on Play store Icon.

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346557/how-to-detect-when-the-user-launches-another-app-android

Comment: please refer my answer in this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25500562/listener-when-an-application-is-started/25500608#25500608

Answer (score 0):

use a Service that tracks all of the running application

please refer the post here

[Listener when an application is started?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25500562/listener-when-an-application-is-started/25500608#25500608)